# Why is canvas working in chrome, but not firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, parallax, requestanimationframe

I'm developing a website that utilizes parallax scrolling. It looks beautiful in chrome, but none of the images i'd like to draw to the canvas are rendering in firefox. I am flummoxed.

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset='utf8'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css'>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id='canvas' width="400" height="200"></canvas>
    <img id='dog' src='dog.gif'>

    <script src='script.js'></script>
</body>

</html>
```

And the Javascript:

```
  //  shim layer with setTimeout fallback
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
  return  window.requestAnimationFrame       ||
          window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
          window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
          window.oRequestAnimationFrame      ||
          window.msRequestAnimationFrame     ||
          function( callback ){
          window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
          };
})();

(function(win, d){

    var $ = d.querySelector.bind(d);
  var w = window.innerWidth;
  var h = d.height;
    var canvas = $('#canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var dog = $('#dog');
  var ticking = false;
  var relativeY = win.scrollY / h;

  function updateElements(){
    ctx.drawImage(dog, 10, pos(50, 0, relativeY, 0));
  };

  function paint(){
    requestAnimFrame(updateElements)
  };

  function onScroll(){
    if(!ticking){
      ticking = true;
      requestAnimFrame(updateElements);
      var lastScrollY = win.scrollY;
    }
  }

    function pos(base, range, relY, offset) {
    return base + limit(0, 1, relY - offset) * range;
  }

  function limit(min, max, value) {
    return Math.max(min, Math.min(max, value));
  }

  win.addEventListener('load', paint, false);
  win.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll, false);

})(window, document);
```

Thank you!

Comment: So, are you getting any errors?

Comment: That's the weird thing, is I'm seeing no errors in the console. None! I have no clue what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

i think firefox not ready to display good performance, because I check by runing game in some diffrent opration system and last version of firefox
and diffrent pc and i get 20 fps

when I run the same game with chrome I got 60 fps

you can try it yourself run this game [tester](http://codeincomplete.com/projects/racer/v4.final.html)

in the left side top you will see small window tester see your performance in firefox it will be 30
i think to bad.